# Distant black effect

Tags: performance, lutris

I have downloaded American Truck Simulator in my Ubuntu 20.04. I am playing with PlayOnLinux and I don't know why my game is running very slow and has this distant black effect. I have downloaded Directx9 and Physx on that directory. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a wine/playonlinux problem rather than an Ubuntu problem. What makes you think it has anything to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: The distance effect looks like it's a tinted windshield.

Comment: Sorry if you are misguided but I want solutions on wine. Because I'm playing it on ubuntu makes it ubuntu problem.

Comment: Yes of course, but large trucks often have dark tinted upper windshields to reduce glare which can cause blind spots, and improve driver safety.

Comment: But It's not like that. I know that It's a wine problem because I've had this problem before.
So, I was thinking that what if I downgrade my wine version to 4.0, will that work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question remains ambiguous because of the screenshot, however this is not important anymore because the OP managed to solve it and answered his own question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem. You have to play this game on gdi direct draw render. You can found this in Display in configure of the directory.